# String array conversion in Kotlin

Tags: android, arrays, string, kotlin, integer

I have the following string and inside the string you can see that there is number of arrays. `"10, 20, 30, 40, 30, 20, 10, 5, 20, 30, 20, 30"`

What I would like to do is basically need to divide this string in each individual strings and would like to convert them in to the integer array.

For example: String array = ["10", "20", "30", "40", "30", "20", "10", "5", "20", "30", "20", "30"] - > Integer array =  [10, 20, 30, 40, 30, 20, 10, 5, 20, 30, 20, 30].

Comment: Where exactly are you stuck with this? `split`, `map`, `trim` and `toInt` could get you there pretty easily. I suggest you break the problem down into smaller steps and research each one in turn.

Answer (score 5):

If you want convert String array to Int array:

```
val stringArray = arrayOf("10", "20", "30", "40", "30", "20", "10", "5", "20", "30", "20", "30")
```

And convert it to int array using map

```
val intArray = stringArray.map { it.toInt() }
```

If you want to print it:

```
print(stringArray)
print(intArray)
```

Or, if you want convert a "String" to int array, you need split it and map.

```
val inputString = "10, 20, 30, 40, 30, 20, 10, 5, 20, 30, 20, 30"
val intArray = inputString.split(", ").map { it.toInt() }
```

Comment: `intArray` here is of type `List<Int>` rather than `IntArray`, so its variable name is misleading.

Answer (score 0):

Assuming you have a string has an array in it. This following code should give you what you want.

```
val array = "[20, 30, 40, 30, 20, 10, 5, 20, 30, 20, 30]"
val items = array.replace("\\[".toRegex(), "").replace("\\]".toRegex(), "").replace("\\s".toRegex(), "").split(",".toRegex()).dropLastWhile { it.isEmpty() }.toTypedArray()
val results = IntArray(items.size)

for (i in items.indices) {
   results[i] = Integer.parseInt(items[i])
}
```

Comment: using split(",") after removing the square brackets is much easier